# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'putpixel'

Tags: python-3.x

```
    from PIL import Image
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    img2 = cv2.imread("D:/0606/2.jpg")
    grayimg2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow("grayimg2",grayimg2)
    width_2,heigh_2 = grayimg2.shape
    img1 = cv2.imread("D:/0606/1.jpg")
    grayimg1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow("grayimg1",grayimg1)
    width_1,heigh_1 = grayimg1.shape
    for y in range(heigh_2):
        for x in range(width_2):
            i=int(grayimg2[x,y])
            j=int(grayimg1[x,y])
            a=abs(i-j)
            if abs(i-j)>114:
               a=255
            else:
               a=0
            img=[]
            img.putpixel((x,y),a)
```

img.putpixel((x,y),a)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'putpixel'
in my code input two image and convert to graylevel
read each pixel graylevel in img1 and img2
if img2 > img1 put a = 255
else a = 0
how can put "a" in to a new picture and get a new graylevel picture

Comment: `img=[]; img.putpixel(...)` - so, does a list have the `putpixel` method?

Comment: no, putpixel method like this  

from pyx import *
     
from PIL import Image


im = Image.new("RGB", (3, 1))

im.putpixel((0, 0), (255, 0, 0))

im.putpixel((1, 0), (0, 255, 0))

im.putpixel((2, 0), (0, 0, 255))


c = canvas.canvas()

c.insert(bitmap.bitmap(0, 0, im, height=0.8))

c.writeEPSfile("pil")

c.writePDFfile("pil")

c.writeSVGfile("pil")

Comment: Yeah! But in your code, `img` is a _list_. Right before calling `putpixel` you make `img` point to an empty list.

Comment: thank for your recommendation , i solved the problem!!